# Why is the return value of GetType a nullable reference type?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types

Given this:

```
var t1 = new object().GetType();
```

Why would `t1` be a `Type?` instead of `Type`? *A nullable Type vs non-nullable Type.*

[image]

`GetType` is supposed to return a `Type`:

[image]

Comment: Does `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` make a difference?

Comment: I'm assuming people realize we're in a nullable reference type context.

Comment: `GetType()` does return `Type`. The question seems to be - why is the `new` operator returning a nullable?

Comment: Because a decision was made when writing the proposal, due to the sheer volume of existing code where `var` would need to be nullable. And due to the compiler being smart enough to detect possible null usage in local variables.

Comment: If you use the "Use explicit type" refactoring, one of two things will happen. In 17.4.0 or later, it will change to `Type` if the right side isn't nullale. Prior to 17.4.0, it will change to `Type?`. 17.4.0 will still show `Type?` in the tooltip, but nullable analysis can see that it's not going to be null because you assigned a non-nullable result to it. For example, you can call `t1.ToString();` on the next line and it won't give a possible nullable reference warning. Because it's a local variable, it doesn't matter that it's declared nullable if analysis can rule out null immediately.